# what path to use for jsonb_insert when column is a json array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a postgres table with a column (information) that looks like this

```
[
  {
    "col": "title",
    "source": film.title
    "width": 100
  },
  {
    "col": "director",
    "source": film.director,
    "width": 150
  },
  {
    "col": "year",
    "source": film.releaseyear,
    "width": 40
  }
]
```

How do I add to array after the director element so it looks like this

```
[
  {
    "col": "title",
    "source": film.title
    "width": 100
  },
  {
    "col": "director",
    "source": film.director,
    "width": 150
  },
  {
    "col": "length",
    "source": film.duration,
    "width": 50
  },
  {
    "col": "year",
    "source": film.releaseyear,
    "width": 40
  }
]
```

I know it's the jsonb_insert function but I'm not sure what the path should be. I tried
`jsonb_insert(information, {1}, filmLength::jsonb, true)` but that doesn't work.
My confusion is that the array I'm inserting into is the whole json not just a key/value in the object.

Comment: You have to specify the array as either `'{1}'` (quotes) or `ARRAY['1']`.

Comment: Your JSON does not seem to be valid? see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=b6055fc3e6fd7020eb5701010f3714d0

Comment: see solution in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=9209e23588e8bd505b5d239fcab5d4ac)